# Existence of certain points in the cubic curve group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a nonsingular cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ and $P$ a point in $C$. Consider the well known group structure on $C$ with its binary operation $+$. Assume that the neutral element is chosen to be an inflection point.

How to see (preferably as elementary as possible) that there is a point $Q$ in $C$ so that $Q+Q=P$? What about the existence of a point $R_n$ in $C$ so that $nR_n = P$ with $n\geq 3$?

Answer (score 1):

Given any point in the plane, there is at least one line through that point which is tangential to your curve. Now, take the point $-P\in C$ and draw a line through $-P$ tangential to $C$, say at $Q$. Then $-P+2Q=0$, solving your problem for $2Q=P$.

Comment: Why is there at least one tangential line going through any given point?

Comment: One way to see why is to project the curve to a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ from the chosen point. The map from $C$ to the line must ramify by Riemann-Hurwitz. The line from your chosen point to any ramification point will be tangent to the curve at the ramification point.